# Round numbers to 50 thousands in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rounding

How can I round a number to the nearest up or down 50 thousand?

I want to round this `542756` to this `550000`, or round this `521405` to this `500000`. Considering that the number to be rounded is a variable `x`.

I tried this:

```
import math

def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 50000.0)) * 50000
```

But it only round up and I need to round both up or down.

I also tried this:

```
round(float(x), -5)
```

But this round to the nearest hundred thousand.

I suppose there is a simple solution but couldn't find anything.

Comment: integer or float input? How should halfway cases (e.g., `525000`) be handled? What about negative inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to the nearest 500, Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810391/round-to-the-nearest-500-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
def round_nearest(x,num=50000):
    return int(round(float(x)/num)*num)
```

You can also **avoid** converting to floating point if you deal with **large numbers**. In that case, you can use:

```
def round_nearest_large(x,num=50000):
    return ((x+num//2)//num)*num
```

You can call it with two arguments to round to the nearest `num`, or without will round to the nearest 50000. You can omit the `int(..)` if you do not want the result to be an `int(..)` per se (for instance if you want to round on `0.5` as well). In that case we can define:

```
def round_nearest_float(x,num=50000):
    return round(float(x)/num)*num
```

This produces:

```
>>> round_nearest(542756)
550000
>>> round_nearest(521405)
500000
```

Or if you want another number to round to:

```
>>> round_nearest(542756,1000)
543000
>>> round_nearest(542756,200000)
600000
```

Comment: Just a comment that if it's integer-in, integer-out, then you might be better off using pure integer operations to avoid loss of accuracy from the use of floating-point. E.g., `round_nearest(100000000000000925000)` gives `100000000000000901120`, which is both inaccurate and rounded the wrong way. (But the OP doesn't seem to want to tell us what the requirements are, so it probably doesn't matter.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still unclear what should happen in halfway cases.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yeah the problem is a bit *underspecified*. I agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
def round_nearest(x, multiple):
    return math.floor(float(x) / multiple + 0.5) * multiple

>>> round_nearest(542756, 50000)
550000
>>> round_nearest(521405, 50000)
500000
```

Answer (score 1):

`divmod` could be your friend in this case

```
def roundmynumber(x):
    y,z = divmod(x,50000)
    if z >25000: y +=1
    return int(50000*y)

>>> roundmynumber(83000)
100000
>>> roundmynumber(13000)
0
>>> roundmynumber(52000)
50000
>>> roundmynumber(152000)
150000
>>> roundmynumber(172000)
150000
>>> roundmynumber(152000.045)
150000
>>> roundmynumber(-152000.045)
-150000
```

Comment: Using `24999.99` here isn't a good idea. If you want to compare with `25000`, compare with `25000`.

Comment: took your advice!